# ACE editor with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ace-editor

How can I use ACE editor with webpack ?
ACE editor can load extensions like syntax highlights, or code snippets dynamically. But, webpack tries to load scripts statically.

Answer (score 4):

You could use brace which is browserify compatible

`npm install --save brace`

Then in one of your javascript files you can include it like so

`var brace = require('brace');
require('brace/mode/javascript');
require('brace/theme/monokai');`

If your using webpack with es6 you can do

`import brace from 'brace'
import 'brace/mode/javascript'
import 'brace/theme/monokai'`

You can see more here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/brace

I use a react wrapper of ace which can be found here

https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace

Comment: I need to support many languages, styles so that users can switch language or style instantly.

Comment: This seems to throw CSP errors. Have you resolved that behavior? Modifying the `devtools` parameter in the `webpack.config.js` does not seem to stop the CSP errors.